# Instagam Getting Invalid platform app Error

Tags: instagram-api, react-native-instagram-login

```
{"error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "Invalid platform app"}
```

I get this error when authenticating using Auth0.

Thanks in advance